# I want to automate the sas code for every month

Tags: sas

I am calculating around **12 metrics (Say Sales for each month individually for latest 12 months)**. Every month I need to go manually and change the month everywhere.  If there is any way to automate it, it would be very helpful.  My code is

```
proc sql;
create table inter.calls as
select a.district_name, 
       sum(01JAN2016,01FEB2016,01MAR2016)/terr_count as q1_workingdays,
       sum(01APR2016,01JUN2016,01MAY2016)/terr_count as q2_workingdays,
       sum(01AUG2016,01SEP2016,01JUL2016)/terr_count as q3_workingdays,
       sum(01NOV2016,01DEC2016,01OCT2016)/terr_count as q4_workingdays
from inter.calls_made_bymon_reg3 a left join inter.territory_count b
on a.district_name=b.district_name;
quit;
```

Now when I refresh for JAN2017, I need to change from FEB2016 to JAN2017 for latest 12months. Every time it is difficult to change the code manually.

I will be very thankful if I get any help!!

Comment: That isn't valid SAS code since those aren't valid SAS names. I highly suggest reformatting your data and then using the QTR() functions to determine the quarter and you can automate this very easily.

Comment: Hi Reeza, sorry for mentioning it wrongly and it will be something like below:`sum(days_01JAN2016,days_01FEB2016....)`  Thanks  @Reeza

Comment: For the _QTR()_ function, how to change quarter for every latest month.  Say JAN2017 is latest month, then my q4 should be like `sum(NOV2016, DEC2016, JAN2017)`  Is there a way to do this? @Reeza

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your problem completely, because as Reeza mentioned the arguments in your `sum()` functions are invalid (the names begin with a number).

However, I do understand the desire not to manually change dates all over the place. You might find a macro like the below helpful:

```
%macro prev_month(n);
    %let latest_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&latest_month.,monyy7.)),-&n.));
    days_%sysfunc(putn(&latest_date.,monyy7.))
%mend prev_month;
```

And you would then use it in your query like so:

```
%let latest_month = JAN2017;
proc sql;
    create table inter.calls as
    select a.district_name, 
           sum(%prev_month(11),%prev_month(10),%prev_month(9))/terr_count as q1_workingdays,
           sum(%prev_month(8) ,%prev_month(7) ,%prev_month(6))/terr_count as q2_workingdays,
           sum(%prev_month(5) ,%prev_month(4) ,%prev_month(3))/terr_count as q3_workingdays,
           sum(%prev_month(2) ,%prev_month(1) ,%prev_month(0))/terr_count as q4_workingdays
    from inter.calls_made_bymon_reg3 a left join inter.territory_count b
    on a.district_name=b.district_name;
quit;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the code. I had a doubt!! if i have a column like days_01JAN2016, then should i call in sum function as:  `sum(days_%prev_month(11)` @Hugs

Comment: It's not working. It seems we cannot call macros inside sas function. It's throwing me error. @Hugs

Comment: @Shalini, I think a `;` in the macro definition was causing problems. I've edited the answer. See if that works?